# Cannot find a class

Tags: ruby, rdoc

You can use Octopussy like this:

```
Octopussy.user "my_account"
```

But I cannot find the "user" method in the API documentation http://rdoc.info/github/pengwynn/octopussy/master/Octopussy

According to the documentation that module is extended by SingleForwardable.

That module has to contain the method "user" but I cannot find that module.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://github.com/pengwynn/octopussy/blob/master/lib/octopussy/client.rb, line 21
I am not really familiar with SingleForwardable, but I am assuming this line in octopussy.rb forwards the following calls to Octopussy to client

```
def_delegators :client, :search_users, :user, :followers, :following, :follows?, :watched
```

As for why you can't find it, that is because it is an rdoc against undocumented code, which is next to useless. For really small things like this with a crappy rdoc, it is often best to just crack open the source (and pray that whoever wrote it kept things simple)